# Swagger UI AuthHeader Filter - Authroize Filter not in FilterDescriptors

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger-ui, asp.net-core-3.0, asp.net-authorization

I have a Swagger UI setup for my API and am looking to add an Authorization parameter for controller methods with the `[Authorize]` attribute from `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization`

Currently I have a custom filter class setup through googling how to do so which looks like this:

```
public class AuthHeaderFilter : Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.IOperationFilter
{
    public void Apply(OpenApiOperation operation, OperationFilterContext context)
    {
        var filterPipeline = context.ApiDescription.ActionDescriptor.FilterDescriptors;
        var isAuthorized = filterPipeline.Select(filterInfo => filterInfo.Filter).Any(filter => filter is AuthorizeFilter);
        var allowAnonymous = filterPipeline.Select(filterInfo => filterInfo.Filter).Any(filter => filter is IAllowAnonymousFilter);

        if (isAuthorized && !allowAnonymous)
        {
            if (operation.Parameters == null)
                operation.Parameters = new List<OpenApiParameter>();

            operation.Parameters.Insert(0, new OpenApiParameter
            {
                Name = "Authorization",
                In = ParameterLocation.Header,
                Description = "access token",
                Required = true,
                Schema = new OpenApiSchema
                {
                    Type = "String",
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that no methods are getting the authorization parameter added on the UI. I debugged this class with the methods that had the authorize attribute being applied to them and found that the problem is that the filterPipeline derived from the FilterDescriptors doesn't contain the AuthorizeFilter. Is there something that needs added into the startup class that handles how this attribute is added to the filters that I'm missing?

Comment: In OpenAPI 3.0, header parameters named `Authorization` [are ignored](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/3.0.2.md#user-content-parametername). You need to configure this header as a [security scheme](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore#add-security-definitions-and-requirements) instead.

Comment: @Helen Ah that's why. Wonder why they changed that... Oh well thanks for the help! Got it setup and working now. If you want to post an answer, I'll be happy to accept it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In OpenAPI 3.0, header parameters named `Authorization` [are ignored](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/3.0.2.md#user-content-parametername). You need to configure this header as a [security scheme](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore#add-security-definitions-and-requirements) instead.